# Disable multiple taps on uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a uitableview that implements a popover ([PopoverView](https://github.com/runway20/PopoverView)) when a cell is tapped and then the popover will dismiss on any other tap on the screen.  The issue is that if a user would to double tap or tap repeatedly on the cell, it will cause multiple instances of popoverviews to display and then the application will crash..  I am looking for a way to either disable double tapping on the cell and/or the `UITableView` in general OR is there a way to delay touches on a `UITableViewCell` any ideas?

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031254/how-can-i-detect-a-double-tap-on-a-certain-cell-in-uitableview) but it does not work in my case.
Another approach would to be to check if PopoverView is already present, if so then don't allow another one to instantiate. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777438/how-to-tell-if-uiviewcontrollers-view-is-visible) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503187/uiview-how-to-find-out-if-a-view-is-already-exists) and both do not work in my case.

Here is my code where I call the popover view on `didSelectRowAtIndexpath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
sti = [[SelectedTeamsInfo alloc] init];
MyLeagueStandings *info = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[sti getAllScheduleForTeam:info.urlforteam];
NSString *title = info.teamname;

// If title length is greater then 32 truncate it to fit.
if (title.length > 32) {
    title = [info.teamname substringToIndex:29];
    title = [title stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
}


[PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:cell.center inView:self.view withTitle:title withContentView:sti.view delegate:self];
}
```

**SOLUTION**:

In interface class:

```
 BOOL PopoverYN;
```

In Implementation class:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // If the popover is not available then display it else do nothing since one is already displayed.
        if (PopoverYN == NO) {
            PopoverYN = YES;
            UITableViewCell *cell = [TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            sti = [[SelectedTeamsInfo alloc] init];
            MyLeagueStandings *info = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [sti getAllScheduleForTeam:info.urlforteam];
            NSString *title = info.teamname;

            // If title length is greater then 32 truncate it to fit.
            if (title.length > 32) {
                title = [info.teamname substringToIndex:29];
                title = [title stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
            }
            [PopoverView showPopoverAtPoint:cell.center inView:self.view withTitle:title withContentView:sti.view delegate:self];
        }

}

#pragma mark - popover methods.
- (void)popoverViewDidDismiss:(PopoverView *)popoverView;
{
    PopoverYN = NO;
}
```

Comment: this is one of those questions I have trouble answering because I have so many answers. you're going to have to tell a variable your popover is being called and to ignore anything else until you get back. basically wrapping what is in your didselectrowatIndexPath method inside of a if statement that checks a BOOL that you will reset when the view is back

Comment: Your comment was also extremely helpful thank you.

Comment: Glad to here it and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the popover to a property on that view.  Clear that when it is dismissed (via delegate method).  In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` don't create another popover if the first has not been dismissed.

Comment: Perfect thank you! The delegate method and property is what did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I have one more solution. Hope this will help someone. If you want to detect the second tap and consume it then this is it, this worked for me. I was loading web view on single tap, if there are two consecutive taps, the bug was getting `NSURLErrorCancelled` event and was causing white flash screen on `webview`. I could handle it at web view level but I though I should kill the problem at root.

```
NSTimer *avoidDoubleTapTimer;

- (void) onTimer {  
    NSLog(@"Timer out");
    avoidDoubleTapTimer = nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(avoidDoubleTapTimer == nil) {
        avoidDoubleTapTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Double Tap Detected");
        return;
    }
// do you stuff on single tap
}
```

Comment: This worked and is the best answer that found so far! I had to set it to 1 sec. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Swift version of [@mask answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22999019/4833705) but my `withTimeInterval` time duration worked better with 2 secs instead of 1.

It should be noted that even though this timer doesn't repeat it was causing a problem after I tapped a cell, the new vc got pushed on, I returned to the parent (the one with the timer), then switched tabs. The tab was frozen. After several tries of commenting and uncommenting out the timer I realized it was the timer.

To fix I just cancelled the timer in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
var avoidDoubleTapTimer: Timer?

@objc func cancelDoubleTapTimer() {
    avoidDoubleTapTimer = nil
}

// use it for a cell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if avoidDoubleTapTimer == nil {

        avoidDoubleTapTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { [weak self](_) in
            self?.cancelDoubleTapTimer()
        })
    } else {

        return
    }

    // run your code, do whatever ...
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    cancelDoubleTapTimer()
}

// or use it for a tapGestureRecognizer

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelWasTapped))
yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

@objc func labelWasTapped() {

    if avoidDoubleTapTimer == nil {

        avoidDoubleTapTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { [weak self](_) in
            self?.cancelDoubleTapTimer()
        })

    } else {

        return
    }

    // run your code, do whatever ...
}
```